# nmodbus ReadHoldingRegisters freeze

Tags: c#, modbus

I am trying to read modbus registers from a COM port I am using the NModbus4 registers but when using the readHoldingRegister it will simply freeze there.
This is my source code:

```
public static void ModbusSerialAsciiMasterReadRegisters()
    {
        using (SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM4"))
        {
            // configure serial port
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.Open();

            var adapter = new SerialPortAdapter(port);

            var factory = new ModbusFactory();

            // create modbus master
            IModbusSerialMaster master = factory.CreateAsciiMaster(adapter);

            byte slaveId = 1;
            ushort startAddress = 8193;
            ushort numRegisters = 5;

            // read five registers      
            try
            {
                ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);
                for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Register {startAddress + i}={registers[i]}");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ReadTimeout ou WriteTimeout. In my case i use 200ms.

```
port.ReadTimeout = 200;
port.WriteTimeout= 200;
```

For my use case, if takes more then 200ms to communicate, it is because hardware is not there. Dependent on what hardware your communication with, you must change this value.

**EDIT:** Just an off-topic improvement: IModbusSerialMaster is IDisposable. Put it in an `using` block

Hope this helps.